# Error installing the correct version of pywin32 to install pybrowsers in python

Tags: python, installation, browser

I'm trying to install the pybrowsers module in python. I tried installing it, using my normal command in the command prompt. I got a conflict error, that apparently my current version of pywin32 was too high, it needed to be lower than 306. So I uninstalled pywin32, but when I tried to install it again to the correct version, I got another error: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement... so I'm at a little bit of a loss as to how to proceed.

Comment: which version of windows? x32 or x64? and which python version?

Comment: x64, my current python version is 3.12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pybrowsers currently supports Python 3.7 - 3.11](https://pypi.org/project/pybrowsers/#data). There's no support yet for your python 3.12.1.

To resolve your issue, install a supported version (you can have multiple versions of Python in your system) and use virtual environments to manage projects that requires specific python versions.

For example you can create a Python 3.11 virtual environment and install pybrowsers in that environment.